# Neo4J Cypher Pattern syntax

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am learning Neo4J, and while reading the book "Graph Databases" by O'Reilly, I came across a graph pattern which describes three friends, represented as nodes and the relationship direction between them signifying who is whose friend.

Here's the diagram - [image]

From the diagram, I can understand that - `b knows a, c knows a and c knows b`

But the Cypher query pattern isn't clear to me -

```
(a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)-[:KNOWS]->(c), (a)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
```

On the next section, where they describe the syntax, they mention -

> Using ASCII characters to represent nodes and relationships, we draw
>   the data we're interested in. We use parantheses to draw nodes, and
>   pairs of dashes and greater-than and less-than sign to draw
>   relationships(- -> and <- -). The < and > signs indicate relationship
>   direction.

If this is the case, `(a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)-[:KNOWS]->(c)` signifies that `a KNOWS b` and `b KNOWS c`, and `(a)-[:KNOWS]->(c)` signifies that `a KNOWS c`. Isn't this the opposite of what the arrows in the diagram depict?

Comment: It is Cypher with a *Y* :)

Comment: My apologies! One of the downfalls of being a *beginner*, yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be a mistake in the book. The shown diagram is expressed by

```
(a)<-[:KNOWS]-(b)<-[:KNOWS]-(c), (c)-[:KNOWS]->(a)
```

or

```
(a)<-[:KNOWS]-(b)<-[:KNOWS]-(c)-[:KNOWS]->(a)
```